# How do I remove the hover effect of menu separators?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

In my salient WordPress theme, this is the css for my menu.

```
header#top nav > ul > li > a {
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 23.8px;
}
```

I have this code for menu separator "|". **I want to remove the hover effect for the menu separators** i.e., when I hover the mouse only menus should change the color and not the separators along with menus also.

```
media="all"
header#top nav > ul > li > a::after {
    content: "|";
    padding-right: .8em;
    padding-left: .8em;
}
```

**Edit:** Adding :hover code

```
a:hover {
color: inherit;
}

header#top nav ul li a:hover,
header#top nav .sf-menu li.sfHover > a,
header#top nav .sf-menu li.current_page_ancestor > a,
header#top nav .sf-menu li.current-menu-item > a,
header#top nav .sf-menu li.current-menu-ancestor > a,
header#top nav .sf-menu li.current_page_item > a {
color: #27CFC3;
} 

.sf-menu li ul li a:hover, .sf-menu li ul li.sfHover > a { 
color: #27CFC3;
background-color: #272727!important;    
}
```

Comment: Can you produce a JSFiddle link to the issue?

Comment: Can you show us the selector you're using for the hover styles

Comment: css hover selector is literally `:hover {`, unless you have this in your css, the hover effect is being performed with javascript.

Comment: Have you tried changing *header#top nav > ul > li > a::after* to *header#top nav > ul > li::after* ?

Comment: I think it is difficult to add js code in my Wordpress theme. I will add the :hover code.

Comment: @Chandz, you dont need to 'add' anything, you need to **remove** the hover part. if your want to remove the hover effect then you need to dig though the code and find what causes the hover effect and remove it.

Comment: is this describe your problem http://jsfiddle.net/vhsc1563/3/

Comment: @kerrel: Yes I tried. But its not working. Still menu separator is taking hover effect color :(

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure the `::after` rule is declared after the `:hover` rule and specify its `color`.

**EXAMPLE**

```css
a{
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover{
    color:red;
}
a::after{
    color:black;
    content:"|";
    padding:0 5px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">link</a>
```

Comment: Yes bro my code is at the end of the page. I think the problem is its inheriting the properties:
header#top nav > ul > li > a::after

Answer (score 0):

my problem solved. I just added **color** property in my menu-separator css code:

```
media="all"
header#top nav > ul > li > a::after 
{
content: "|";
padding-right: .8em;
padding-left: .8em;
color: #008daa!important; //I inserted this line. It works perfect now!
}
```

Color property overrode all the hovering changing color properties.
Thank you very much for all of your immediate support.